# Javascript and regex for link and youtube

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace the text links to html view , except that YouTube, it must be replaced by a picture.

```
var message = "";
message = value['message'].replace(/((.[^>"]|[^=]")\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/([-A-Z0-9+&@#%?=~_|!:,.;]*)([-A-Z0-9+&@#%?\/=~_|!:,.;]*)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig, "<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>");

message = message.replace(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((.|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/, "<img src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/$1/0.jpg' class='youtube_preview' onclick='showYoutube(\"$1\")'>");
```

But in the result this JS code shows only youtube image. What's wrong?

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/c2376yfx/

After run JS code, show only links, but youtube link should be a picture.

Comment: The final *thanks* sounded like *do it for me*, which is not the purpose of stackoverflow and your question might have faced quick close. My edit wasn't the best, just a hint: you have better chances for the answer if you form the question to improve your understanding, not to correct your code to fit your purpose. So try to further improve your question.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c2376yfx/

Answer (score 0):

So... You want to replace the link with a link to an image?

... Just replace the YT link at target.html and src with the image link.